# Unable to get data from Default and other user define schemas in Hbase using apache phoneix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to get table data for ("default") schema in Hbase using Apache phoenix. And my request body is as follows:

```
{"request": "getTables","connectionId":"1875901652","schemaPattern":"default"}
```

and the response contains rows as empty else returned it as internal server error. Note: I have changed the connectionId for each and every request,but still the issue exists.Similarly for other schema also.Only for "System" schema able to get the data. Please let know the reason and how to resolve the same. Thanks in advance.